# Why does it throw Invalid expression exception for Azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I receive this

> Invalid expression: Syntax error at position 8 in '$filter=search.in(Categories, 'Career Resources', ',')'.
>   Parameter name: $filter

exception when performing a search in Azure.

Here is the code snippet by itself

```
$filter=search.in(Categories, 'Career Resources', ',')
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add some details about how you’re sending the request? For example, are you using the REST API or .NET SDK? Some code that shows how you set the filter parameter would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by using a completely different syntax:

```
"Categories/any(f: f eq 'Career Resources')"
```

Answer (score 0):

The search.in function got two overloads:

1. search.in(variable, valueList)
2. search.in(variable, valueList, delimiters)

so in you are case,

1. if you are searching for "Career Resources" then syntax will be

   ```
     $filter=search.in(Categories, 'Career Resources')
   ```
2. And if you are searching for "Career" or "Resources" then syntax will be

   ```
    $filter=search.in(Categories, 'Career,Resources' ',')
   ```

Comment: I don't think that would explain the syntax error that @Hoodlum is seeing.

Comment: What @Bruce said. And it also worth mentioning that these two filters are the same because the default delimiters are space AND comma. So the OP's filter is actually correct for searching "Career Resources".